# PostgreSQL 13: error number of items mismatch in GIN entry tuple, 2 in tuple header, 19 decoded

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I stuck with a problem with PostgreSQL at GCP that at some moment PostgreSQL starts to raise an error

```
number of items mismatch in GIN entry tuple, 2 in tuple header, 19 decoded
```

It happens after insert in the table with GIN index on JSONB field
After the first occurrence of the error, it will occur regularly, but not on every insert operation

I tried to reinsert to test DB the same rows, several rows before and after the error appeared, everything was inserted successfully

Also, I see in the Postgres logs before the error starts to appear: `automatic analyze of table <table-name>`, maybe it can be helpful

Answer (score 2):

That is some kind of data corruption. If you want that investigated, you'll have to ask your hosting provider.

To get rid of the message, rebuild the index using `REINDEX`.